# why there are so many posts whoes post_type is revision? will these records waste too much database space?

Tags: posts, database, post-status, post-type, revisions

from the following data we may know there are only 30 records which are meaningful, and there are 92 records of revision post_type which can not be shown on the blog.

so will these records waste too much database space?

is it recommended to save such kind of revisions?  (btw, i may edit my blog oftenly)

```
mysql> select count(*),post_type, post_status from wp_137_posts group by post_type, post_status;
+----------+-----------+-------------+
| count(*) | post_type | post_status |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
|        1 | page      | publish     |
|        2 | post      | auto-draft  |     // also, should i delete this record?
|       30 | post      | publish     |
|       92 | revision  | inherit     |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.24 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you edit a post/page, WordPress creates timely revisions of it. Check the Firebug console for the requests that are sent at regular intervals when you are on the edit page. They are useful if you lose the post content at some point and want to get back to an earlier version of the post. Once you publish the final version of the post then you can delete all the post revisions.

And yes, they do take up your database space!

**Solution:**
There's an excellent answer [over here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71248/delete-revisions-on-post-publish).

Comment: how to delete these revisions, since there maybe more than 20 revisions ...

Comment: 20 is pretty less! There could be a lot more. Check this post by Lester Chan... http://lesterchan.net/wordpress/2008/07/17/how-to-turn-off-post-revision-in-wordpress-26/

Comment: how to delete all the post revisions once i publish the final version?

Comment: Check my edit, I have added a link to an answer on WPSE.